# Search with Javascript

Tags: javascript, class

This is my JavaScript code to find elements with desired `.text()` but it's not working.

```
var divCollection = getElementByClass("titletrack");
for (var i=0; i<divCollection.length; i++) {
  if(divCollection[i].text() == title) {
    findMeText = divCollection[i].text();
    alert(findMeText);
  }
}
```

Comment: jQuery would make your task alot easier.

Comment: What is it doing? What did you expect it to do?

Comment: getElementByClass is not a valid JS function, .text() is not a valid JS function, title is not defined. I'd suggest you start with a basic tutorial on JavaScript and when you get stuck with something you can come back here and provide a meaningful question. At the moment, you're question doesn't make much sense and we can't provide a decent answer.

Comment: Define 'not working'. I suppose you are getting a 'method is undefined' error, because you are using a method from jQuery, and don't list it in the keywords as library you are using.

Comment: its document.getElementsByClassName()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pgPgR/1/)

Hope this is what you had in mind. This may look complicated and im sure there is a simpler way of doing it. But it works.

```
var divCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("titletrack");

for (var i = 0; i < divCollection[0].childElementCount; i++) {
    if (divCollection[0].children[i].textContent == "Element 1") {
        findMeText = divCollection[0].children[i].textContent;
        alert(findMeText);
    }
}
```

Now you can compare any element of the divCollection with any string that you want. In the fiddle i have used the string "Element 1" to demonstrate the working of the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var divCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('titletrack');
```

That is, getElementsByClassName instead of getElementByClass.

Something like this would finish the deal:

```
var str = '';
var strSearchingFor = 'foo';
for(var i=0; i < divCollection .length; i++)
{
    str+= " " + divCollection[i].value;
    if(str == strSearchingFor)
    {
        alert("found");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementByClass is not consistently implemented (see http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=30857) - I'd recommend using jQuery or similar if you don't want to deal with these browser inconsistencies:

```
var divCollection = $('.titletrack');
```

Comment: I was thinking more like `$('.titletrack[text='+title+']').something()`  --- he is vague at this point.  Surely echoing the text back four or five times would be pointless.

Answer (score 0):

There's not `element.text()` method in native javascript. Use `element.textContent` instead.

You can also use `if(divCollection[i].textContext.indexOf(title) != -1)` to check if the element contains the title instead of is equal to it ;-)

Comment: Can you copy/paste the log of error? (you can get it from the console in the chrome devtools)

Comment: @GiorgiChumburidze take a look at my answer if you didn't notice it.